# DynamoDB Conversion Schema V2

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, dotnet-sdk

I read the little documentation that exists about the DynamoDB Conversion Schema for DotNet SDK.
The V2 is now available and adds some new types and changes some type conversions.
Can anybody state if the V2 Schema is backwards compatible?

That is, we have used the V1 schema sofar, and V2 seems like has solved some of the problems that we were facing with V1. Can we just change to V2 and our current applications won't break?

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-series-conversion-schemas/

------
    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268984/how-to-store-a-list-of-strings-with-duplicates-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Object Persistence Model. I had to change those types with new type mapping, for example, int[], to the HashSet.

I also found this in the AWS SDK,
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Custom/Conversion/V1PropertyConverters.cs

For example, if you are using List<>, you can set a specific property to convert using the V1 behaviour.

```
//[DynamoDBProperty(Converter = typeof(SetPropertyConverter<List<byte>,byte>))]
[DynamoDBProperty(Converter = typeof(ListToSetPropertyConverter<byte>))]
public List<byte> KeySizes { get; set; }
```

(https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/test/NetStandard/IntegrationTests/IntegrationTests/DynamoDB/DataModelTests.cs)